# TCPClient connecting to ip list

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy, indy10

I am  new in coding client/server specially in indy, what I'm trying to do with my TCPClient here is if the main server IP is offline it will try to connect to the other ip, Any idea how to do that ? I'm just guessing it would be like...

```
  IdTCPClient1.ReuseSocket := rsTrue;
  IdTCPClient1.BoundIP :=   '192.168.1.31'; //other ip here
  IdTCPClient1.BoundPort := 5000;
  IdTCPClient1.Host := 'localhost';//main ip server here
  IdTCPClient1.Port := 5000;

  IdTCPClient1.Connect;
```

But im getting an error: "Count not bind socket." or "Address is already in use".

Comment: general advice, if you do not have really massive and frequent data exchange, like torrents: dozens of GB split to millions of short isolated packets, better use HTTP + JSON. It is textual and standard = a damn lot of tools to debug any problem, including your own eyes, no problem with firewalls and half-dozen libraries for Delphi that you can choose from for any reason from "does not work" to "do not like"

Comment: I would leave `BoundPort` alone (`0`) and let the OS choose a free port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read http://www.delphigroups.info/2/7/199566.html about BoundIP.

You cannot make TCPClient into scrolling list of ips. If you could - there would be a array-like property where you could put 10 or 100 of addresses, not as little as only two.

What you really have to do - is actually try to connect to different address

Example:

```
function TryToConnect(const server: string): boolean; overload;
begin
  try
    IdTCPClient1.ReuseSocket := rsTrue;
    IdTCPClient1.Host := server;
    IdTCPClient1.Port := 5000;

    IdTCPClient1.Connect;
    Result := true;
  except on E: Exception do begin
    Result := false;
    LogToFileAndScreenAnError(E.ClassName + ' ==> ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;

function TryToConnect(const servers: array of string): boolean; overload;
var i: integer;
begin
  Result := false;
  for i := Low(servers) to High(Servers) do begin
      Result := TryToConnect( servers[i] );
      if Result then break;
  end;


  if not Result then LogAndShowError('Could not connect to any of servers! Read log file!');

 { or maybe even

  if not Result then raise Exception.Create('Could not connect to any of servers! Read log file!');

 }
end;


var ss: TStringDynArray;

SetLength(SS, 2);
ss[0] := 'localhost';
ss[1] := '192.168.3.10';

Success := TryToConnect(ss);
```